# Seeking shapefiles of world in pre-WW2?

Tags: shapefile, data, historical-maps

I'm in search for shapefiles that show all countries of the world as they looked like in the early 1930s, somewhen between WW1 and WW2.
I have some for Europe for the different years of the 20th century, but I still need those for the other continents (esp. the countries in the African continents have changed a lot since then)...

Does someone know where to find them?

Comment: If you are seeking open data the I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Right comment from @PolyGeo: I was curios about and found: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11009/where-can-i-get-shapefiles-for-changing-german-territory-during-the-second-world.

Answer (score -2):

Many historic shapefiles of the countries of the world can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20080328104539/http://library.thinkquest.org:80/C006628/download.html), this includes data of (but not limited to) 1914, 1920, and 1938. However, it looks like there is a gap at the early 1930s, but maybe it's still sufficient.